# Implenting multiple colors on axis line based on axis values in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to know if it is possible to create a plot using ggplot2 where e.g. the x axis line is black from 0 to 5 and white from 5 to 8?

I am working on a plot where there is a column of text on the right side of the plot. Currently, the x axis goes to 8. I am using

```
plot + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 8))
```

If I change the upper limit in the above to 5, I lose the text on the right side. Therefore, I am thinking that simply coloring the x axis white from 5 to 8 would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(
   x = runif(10),
   y = runif(10)
)

ggplot(df) + 
   geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
   geom_segment(aes(y = 0, yend = 0, x = 0, xend = 0.5), color = 'blue') + 
   geom_segment(aes(y = 0, yend = 0, x = 0.5, xend = 1), color = 'red')
```